# Checkout page address selection

Tags: checkout, shipping-address

How to change the checkout page address selection option box instead of dropdown?

Ex:

```
<option value="2" id="billing_address"></optio><br>test Test <br> Address1<br> Chennai<br>Tamil Nadu <br>600001
```

New Address

Comment: where to add "selectToRadio" functions

Comment: In any javascript file that is loaded in the checkout page. Or you can create a new one so you don't interfere with the existing ones and include that in the checkout page.

Comment: Hi, I'm using onepage checkout extension, your code working but not showing New Address form and not refreshing shipping method based on the address selection.

Comment: The script I provided works only with jQuery. Make sure you have JQuery in your website.

Comment: Change to what? I don't understand the question.

Comment: We need to show the address option box instead of selection. Some address have long length. So we not able to see the full address. so need to show the address in option selection.